# How to inspect a single layer within a Docker image?

Tags: image, docker, docker-container, docker-image, docker-layer

I need to get more information on a single layer -- possibly by the layer id -- such as Created & Last Modified date.

Is there anything similar to `docker image inspect` for a single layer within a Docker image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dive tool](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive). It allows to view file changes in the image file system between layers

Comment: @andreagalle was this helpful in solving your issue? if so please accept the answer with the check mark

Comment: I didn't want to use any tool other than Docker itself. Although yours is a powerful option to get inside each single layer, what I needed was something much simpler/basic.

Comment: you can use the dive docker image https://github.com/wagoodman/dive#installation if that makes things easier